# How can I convert SAS dataset into Parquet file via Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: sas, jupyter, parquet

Would you be able to provide guidance on how to convert SAS dataset into Parquet file via Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/sas7bdat/ Import the data using above package and then create file as desired.

Comment: @Reeza Please post your answer as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Read the SAS dataset into python with saspy,

```
import saspy
sas = saspy.SASsession()
mydata = sas.sasdata('mydata')
```

then write the file out

```
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

#arrow
mydata.to_arrow('/path/to/my/arrow/files/myfile.arrow')

#parquet
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
pq.write_table(table, '/path/to/myfile.parquet')
```